# Closed form expression of infinite summation

Tags: summation, closed-form

What is the idea behind a closed form expression and what is the general way of finding the closed form solution of an infinite summation?

context: closed form solution of $\sum^\infty_{i=1}ia^i$.

Comment: It really depends on the form of the expression. What close form do you know?

Comment: A closed-form expression doesn't contain $\infty$. See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743544/are-there-some-techniques-which-can-be-used-to-show-that-a-sum-does-not-have-a/2329022#2329022

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets see:

$\begin{align}
\sum_1^{\infty} ia^i &= a + a^2 + a^2 + a^3 + a^3 + a^3 + ......\\
           &=  \sum_1^{\infty} a^i +  (\sum_2^{\infty} a^i) +  (\sum_3^{\infty} a^i) + ..+  (\sum_{k+1}^{\infty} a^i)+.... \\
          &=  \sum_1^{\infty} a^i + a (\sum_1^{\infty} a^i) + a^2 (\sum_1^{\infty} a^i) + ..+ a^k (\sum_1^{\infty} a^i)+.... \\
           &= \sum_1^{\infty} a^i (1+ a+a^2+....)\\
           &= \sum_1^{\infty} a^i (1+\sum_1^{\infty} a^i)   \\
&= \frac{a}{1-a}(\frac{1}{1-a}) \; \text{if a <1}
\end{align}$

The trick is to look for patterns that repeat themselves.

Answer (score 15):

In general, finding the closed-form of a series or a finite summation is a difficult problem without a general way of attack. For your particular series, if I am correct in assuming that your $a$ is a constant, then let's begin with a geometric series
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$$
Let us now differentiate this series term by term to get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty ix^{i-1}$$
Multiplying by $x$ now gives
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty ix^i$$
The above series will converge for $|x| < 1$, so simply substitute your desired value for $a$ to get the value of the series.

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun, I’ll note that a closed form for the summation $\sum_{k\ge1}kx^k$ can also be found without differentiation:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 1}kx^k&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\sum_{i=1}^kx^k\\\\
&=\sum_{i\ge 1}\sum_{k\ge i}x^k&&\text{reversing the order of summation}\\
&=\sum_{i\ge 1}\frac{x^i}{1-x}&&\text{sum of a geometric series}\\
&=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{i\ge 1}x^i\\
&=\frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac{x}{1-x}\\\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

The closed form in general will be difficult to obtain and how to obtain it will vary from problems to problems. In your case, for $a\in (-1,1)$, the geometric series is given by
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a^i=\frac{1}{1-a},
$$
series being $1$ if $a=0$.

Knowing this, you can see that $ia^{i-1}$ is the derivative of that series, so $\sum_{i=1}^\infty ia^{i-1}$ should be the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-a}$ with respect to $a$. From this, we get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ia^i=a\sum_{i=0}^\infty ia^{i-1}=a\left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)^{'}=\frac{a}{(1-a)^2}
$$
Since our geometric series was valid for $a\in (-1,1)$, this one is also valid for that interval.

Comment: What is wrong with $a=0$? $0^0$?

Comment: meh, good question, I guess i only wanted to avoid $0^0$ issues

Comment: Convention is your friend :-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general procedure. However, analytic functions and their power series representations provide many useful equivalences.

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$, with $|x|<1$. This is analytic, so you can interchange differentiation and summation to get
$f'(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$ (again for $|x|<1$), and finally $xf(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$.

However. I know this because someone showed to me (hundreds of years ago, or so). In general, some guesswork is required.