# Inverse of difference operators

Tags: inverse, finite-differences, discrete-calculus

Given some difference operator of e.g. the form
$$\Delta [f(x)] = f(x+1)-f(x),$$how would I go about finding its inverse $\Delta^{-1}$, so some type of "discrete antiderivative" so that $$\Delta^{-1}[\Delta [f(x)]] = f(x).$$

Comment: For discrete $x$, we can use symbolic summation. Ask here if you need this case.

Comment: @IV_ This is indeed the case, $x$ is supposed to be discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the inverse of the difference operator is the summation operator. If we assume that $x$ runs over the positive integers, then we have the following telescoping sum:

$$\begin{eqnarray}f(x) & = & f(0) + [f(1) - f(0)] + [f(2) - f(1)] + \ldots + [f(x) - f(x-1)] \\ \\
& = & f(0) + \Delta[f(0)] + \Delta[f(1)] + \ldots + \Delta[f(x-1)] \\
& = & f(0) + \sum_{i = 1}^x \Delta[f(i - 1)]
\end{eqnarray}$$

Notice that the $f(0)$ term out the front performs a similar role to the $+C$ in the indefinite integral - in general a discrete difference equation will define a family of functions.

And also just like for the continuous integral, there's no single method to find a closed form for $f(x)$ given a difference equation $\Delta[f(x)] = g(x, f(x))$, but for specific forms of $g(x)$ there are - for example, if $g$ is polynomial in $x$ then $f$ will also be polynomial, if $g$ is a linear function of $f(x)$ then $f$ will involve some kind of exponential term, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1.)

$\Delta\left[f(x)\right]$ is a [forward difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_finite_differences#Basic_types).

The inverse operator of the forward difference operator is the [indefinite sum or antidifference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum).

The inverse difference operator is treated in
Károly Jordán, Charles Jordan: Calculus of Finite Differences. American Mathematical Soc., 1965, 100 ff.: Inverse Operation of Differences and Means. Sums

2.)

If $x$ is discrete, we can use the concepts of Symbolic Summation:

$$\Delta\left[f(k)\right]=f(k+1)-f(k)$$
$$F(k)=\Delta\left[f(k)\right]$$

The goal of Symbolic Summation is to find $f(k)$ for a given $F(k)$:

$$\sum_{k=m}^nF(k)=f(n+1)-f(m)$$

see e.g.:

[Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm)

[Zeilberger's algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html)

[Petkovšek's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petkov%C5%A1ek%27s_algorithm)

[Are there some techniques which can be used to show that a sum "does not have a closed form"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743544/are-there-some-techniques-which-can-be-used-to-show-that-a-sum-does-not-have-a/2329022#2329022)